# Any hanuman mantra which can be recited by anyone without any guru. Also let me know the source

Tags: mantras, hanuman, guru, initiation

Kindly let me know any Hanuman mantra which does not need initiation or Guru

Comment: Even brahmanas aren't allowed to recite Tantrika mantras without having undergone Tantriki diksha. Tantrik texts state the the person who cherry-picks Tantrika mantras from book for recitation brings only harm upon him/herself & such japa is as fruitless as planting a seed on hard rock. At maximum, an adikshita can engage in nama-smarana.

Comment: Hanuman Chalisa of tulsidas

Comment: @AnubrataBit i don't want any tantrik mantra. Nama mantra i need.

Comment: @Youwillnotknowme chalisa is not mantra.

Comment: @Ram According to Brihat-Tantrasara, nama-manttas are composed of pranava in the beginning, the name of the deity iinvoked in chaturthi vibhakti & 'namah' in the end. But those without yajnopavita are forbidden to pronounce the pranava. So Hanumana's nama-mantra would be in this logic is '(ॐ) हनुमते नमः' but I seriously doubt about the effectiveness of such nama-mantras.

Comment: @AnubrataBit there might be nama mantras without pranava Or nama stotras. Please check.

Comment: Is this good @Ram ?
https://www.bhaktibharat.com/mantra/hanuman-dwadash-naam-stotram

Comment: @Apastamba_01yes this stotra is known to me. Any other mantras except hanuman chalisa

Comment: There are no such mantras of lord Hanuman that doesn't require diksha. You need to have but you can chant ram naam, that will awake hanuman ji